# What happened to Freemind?

Tags: 17.10, software-sources

I can no longer find FreeMind in Ubuntu repos and their [homepage](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is mostly blank.

Does anyone know if it's still being actively developed, or are you aware of an alternative software that's capable of opening exising .mm files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You might try Freeplane (sudo apt-get install freeplane). Freeplane is a Freemind fork from about 10 years ago that seems to be in more active development.

AnGus

Comment: thanks, it works on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Thank you, it is working for me on Ubuntu 22.04 ! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can still install FreeMind, and it still works great – in my case, under Ubuntu 18.10. It is no longer provided as a Debian package in the repositories, but as a distribution independent "Snap" package.

You can install it as follows:

1. Assuming you want the latest beta version, which I'd recommend, run this command to install the FreeMind snap ([as documented here](https://snapcraft.io/freemind)):

   ```
   sudo snap install freemind --edge
   ```

   You can now already start FreeMind via the desktop icons and menu entries of your desktop environment.
2. Add the following symlink to be able to start FreeMind from the terminal, Alt+F2 Run Dialog etc.:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /snap/freemind/current/freemind/freemind.sh /usr/local/bin/freemind
   ```

And if you want to uninstall it again:

```
sudo snap remove freemind
```